# Drawing WPF from EndScene hook

Tags: c#, dll, directx, slimdx, scene

I have successfully hooked the EndScene function call from a video game (via managed dll injection). Using SlimDX and a pointer passed to the original EndScene call I manage to acquire the D3D device.

As I have nearly no knowledge of DirectX (or any 3D related library), I am looking for a way to set up WPF so that it renders to the device I want it to.
The desired end result in to have a WPF gui inside my game.
I have no use for input to the gui though - so this can be ignored for now.

Simply put, how would you got about hosting WPF in a D3D fullscreen application (game) ?

Thanks in advance :)